# How do I map this in Java 8 using the stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Ok, so I have a `List<Person>`. and each `Person` has a `List<String>` that is a list of phone numbers that that person owns.

So this is the basic structure:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private List<String> phoneNumbers;

    // constructors and accessor methods

}
```

I would like to create a `Map<String, Person>` where the key is each phone number that the person owns, and the value is the actual person.

So to explain better. If I had this `List<Person>`:

```
Person bob = new Person("Bob");
bob.getPhoneNumbers().add("555-1738");
bob.getPhoneNumbers().add("555-1218");

Person john = new Person("John");
john.getPhoneNumbers().add("518-3718");
john.getPhoneNumbers().add("518-3115");
john.getPhoneNumbers().add("519-1987");

List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(bob);
list.add(john);
```

and I invoked this method. It would give me the following `Map<String, Person>`

```
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("555-1738", bob);
map.put("555-1218", bob);

map.put("518-3718", john);
map.put("518-3115", john);
map.put("519-1987", john);
```

I would like to know how to achieve this using the `stream` API, as I already know how I would do it using `for` loops and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have list of persons called `persons` and a class called `PhoneNumberAndPerson` (you could use a generic `Tuple` or `Pair` instead)

These are the steps:

For each person, take each phone number of that person. For each of those phone numbers, create a new instance of `PhoneNumberAndPerson` and add that to a list. Use flatMap to make one single list of all these smaller lists. To make a `Map` out of this list you supply one function to extract a key from a `PhoneNumberAndPerson` and another function to extract a `Person` from that same `PhoneNumberAndPerson`.

```
persons.stream()
    .flatMap(person -> person.getPhoneNumbers().stream().map(phoneNumber -> new PhoneNumberAndPerson(phoneNumber, person)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(pp -> pp.getPhoneNumber(), pp -> pp.getPerson()));
```

Comment: I see, so a direct mapping wouldn't be possible in this case? Very interesting solution

Comment: Yes if you want a functional solution without side effects then I think you need some extra data structure

Answer (score 4):

Without additional class and pre-creating map:

```
Map<String, Person> result = list.stream().collect(HashMap::new,
     (map, p) -> p.getPhoneNumbers().forEach(phone -> map.put(phone, p)), HashMap::putAll);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without creating other classes i'd go for something like this:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    list.stream().forEach(p -> p.getPhoneNumbers().forEach(n -> map.put(n, p.getName())));
```

Edit: As suggested by Simon, you can use the collect method, but it can be tricky if you want to create a map using the class that you provided, with a simpler class ( without using List but just a plain String in order to store the number) 
you can simply call the code below that returns a Map

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getPhoneNumber, Person::getName));
```

Comment: Hmm.. this has side effects, but is a very clear approach. Very interesting. Thank you